# How can I use test code from pip package?

Tags: python, pip

I have a private python package I am using for a project. In that python package I have unit test that are using fixtures. I want to reuse the fixture in my project.

PACKAGE structure

```
name/
  space/
    __init__.py
    somecode.py
tests/
  fixtures/
    somefixture.py
    name/
      space/
        test_somecode.py
setup.py
```

So when I install the package it just installs the content of `name/space/*`. That's fine.

I am testing, I want to also install that package and be able to use the `tests/fixtures/somefixture.py` in my project. I used `pip -e` to install the package source but not sure how to use the test fixture now.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The setup code within `setup.py` will define the path to the source code relative to itself. It's likely that the `tests` directory is not included in the package's code. Therefore, it won't be bundled into the package archive.

- You could append an absolute path into your `sys.path`, allowing you to import directly.
- You could move the `tests` directory into `name` so it is importable as normal.

Comment: @D Hudson Thanks. Is there a way to package for distribution and package for use in test?

Comment: If you'd like the tests to be part of the package, just move the `tests` folder into `name`. Then import like: `from name.tests import ...`